# Getting exception error when adding [FromBody]

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception

I am trying to debug my code but I am getting `System.NullReferenceException` exception just after adding [frombody] to the parameter but when I removed [frombody] and tried again everything worked normaly

This my controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Register([FromBody] UserForRegisterDTO userForRegisterDTO)
{
    //validate request  

    userForRegisterDTO.Username = userForRegisterDTO.Username.ToLower();   

    if(await _repo.UserExist(userForRegisterDTO.Username))
        return BadRequest("Username is already taken");
}
```

DTO :

```
namespace DatingApp.API.DTO
{
    public class UserForRegisterDTO
    {
        public string Username { get; set; }

        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Postman :
[image]

Error:

> fail:
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pn8Vf.png)
>         An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request. System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

---

## Solved

Something strange happened. I solved this problem by using "dotnet watch run " instead of "dotnet run "

Comment: The problem is definitely the fact that `userForRegisterDTO` is `null`, probably it has no parameterless constructor, please post the source code of the `UserForRegisterDTO` class.

Comment: Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare postman results with your application.  Your request probably is missing a header that is in the postman request.

Comment: have you tried using Form-data instead of raw body type in postman?

Comment: @MartinZikmund check the question now

Comment: Is the controller action marked as `[HttpPost]`?

Comment: @MartinZikmund yes

Comment: Please put a breakpoint in the method and step trhough to see where the exception occurs. I have tested on my PC and the DTO is not `null`. Maybe `_repo` is null?

Comment: i added a breakpoint but i am receiving the exception before detect the breakpoint

Comment: use this modified DTO and let me know => `public class UserForRegisterDTO
    {
        [JsonProperty("username")]
        public string Username { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }`

Comment: @ershoaib still getting same exception

Comment: @ershoaib man if i remove frombody and trying the same example i don't receive an exception

Comment: @JamesFallon, i tried your code with my DTO posted on above comment and i successfully get values inside DTO with [FromBody]

Comment: It works for me even without the `JsonPropertyAttribute`. Could you post he full exception stack trace?

Comment: @MartinZikmund check the exception now

Comment: That still looks incomplete, isn't there a longer trace? And isn't there a `InnerException` with more info?

Comment: no man just  this what i am getting